In Xcode there a way to mark a routine so that 'Step Into' will skip over the routine?
When stepping through code with the debugger using 'Step Into,' Xcode steps into constructors, destructors, and assignment operators. This is especially frustrating when the routine is compiler-supplied. Once a function has been debugged and is error-free, I'd like to be able to skip them during normal 'Step Into'.
Given this code:
#include <vector>

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Object
{
  Object() { };
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class ObjectList : public std::vector<Object>
{
public:
  ObjectList() { };
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
void TestFunction(ObjectList list)
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  ObjectList    list;

  TestFunction(list);

  return 0;
}

When stepping through the above code, when you 'step into' TestFunction(ObjectList list), there is a copy construction of 'ObjectList,' as expected. Xcode jumps to the compiler-generated copy constructor, indicating the line being debugged is class ObjectList : public std::vector line, which tells me nothing. This makes 'step into' cumbersome.
I know you can 'Step Out' when you get there, but that is an additional step that must be recognized and acted upon when stepping and it interferes with the flow without adding any benefit. Of course, the TestFunction signature could be rewritten as void TestFunction(const ObjectList &list) to avoid the copy construction in this case, but I am looking for a general way to avoid the issue.
After I have debugged ObjectList and Object, I would like to tell Xcode not to ever step into any ObjectList or Object function - either on a function-by-function basis or class-by-class basis, sort of like how they would be handled if they were in a library you didn't have the source for.
Is there a way to tell the debugger, "I don't ever want to 'Step Into' this function"?

lldb has a couple of settings to do this, depending on what level you are interested in.  The two settings are:
  target.process.thread.step-avoid-libraries -- A list of libraries that source stepping won't stop in.
  target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp -- A regular expression defining functions step-in won't stop in.

It sounds like the second one is the one you want.  That just takes the regular expression value of the setting and applies it to the demangled function name, and if that regex matches, we don't step into that function.
By default this implements the policy of not stepping into C++ standard library functions (since so much of std is in header files, you actually have debug information for much of the library, and would have the same problem there).  You can see this:
(lldb) settings show target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp
target.process.thread.step-avoid-regexp (regex) = ^std::

So making this ^std::|^ObjectList::|^Object:: should do what you want in your example.  There isn't any Xcode UI to set this variable, but you can play around with it in the lldb console, and if you get a value you like, you can save the value in your ~/.lldbinit or in Xcode you can add a Target specific lldbinit file, and put it there.
